# How do I hide text that is not wrapped in <p> or <span>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html where I only want to hide the text portion, but what complicates it is that it is not wrapped in anything. Below is an example:

```
<div class="content">

    Give comfortable and durable place to work with a desk.
    Lock the center drawer and all of the drawers lock,
    keeping your files and supplies secure.

    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th align="right">Available Options:</th>
                <td>Desktop Color: Fusion Maple, Gray Nebula...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right">Book Box Construction:</th>
                <td>Not applicable</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I hide the "Give comfortable and durable..." portion above without changing the html at all? I was hoping to do it via CSS and maybe Javascript if necessary. CSS only would be perfect though. Can anyone help?

Comment: In you example, none of the texts are wrapped in a `p` or a `span`, do you want to hide everything?

Comment: A very horrible solution might be to change the colour of the text to match that of the background?

Comment: Why can't you just change the HTML?

Comment: I can't change it because it is coming from another system which I have no control over at all. I only want to hide the text above the table. The table I want to still show.

Comment: You should remove the text with whatever programming language you're using to retrieve this HTML. PHP can remove it if you're using that, and so can JavaScript if you're using that. How *are you* retrieving this HTML?

Comment: @TruMan1: Was any of the provided answers helpful/acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look ma', no <s>hands</s> scripts!

### CSS only solution

```
.content
{
    text-indent: -1000em;
}

.content *
{
    text-indent: 0;
}

/* This one's pure cherry on top ;) */
/* Remove excess vertical space */
.content *:first-child
{
    margin-top: -1em;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbh2J/1).

Comment: But that hides the rest of the content in this DIV as well.

Comment: @thirtydot: you were faster writing a JSFiddle demo than I was, but we both came at the same conclusion.

Comment: If you also add `.content table { margin-top: -16px }`, it gets rid of the "one line high gap": http://jsfiddle.net/uU2jv/1/

Comment: would be better to set negative margin as 1em so it doesn't really matter what size your fonts are set... Wouldn't it? ;) And to make it also more universal I updated my CSS so it doesn't really matter what element is first child. Is it a table or is it anything else.

Answer (score 2):

CSS defines the appearance of the contents of a tag. No tag, no styling.

You need to modify the HTML. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This removes the text node, which is a container for the text:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript (and jQuery in my case):

```
var table = $('.content table'); //copy the table
$('.content').html(table); //replace the html of div.content with table
```

If you have multiple classes of `content` then you'll need to rewrite this a bit to work over a collection

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way for that. You'll have to write an html stripper on JavaScript or simply modify your html by hands.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#content {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
or:
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```